# Inifinite loop en get isAdmin method

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a section visible by users who have ADMIN roles only.

In my DB the role_Id for this case is 3.

On the html page I put this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link nav " *ngIf="this.authService.isAdmin" routerLink="/admin"
    routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link nav " *ngIf="!this.authService.isLoggedIn" routerLink="/register"
    routerLinkActive="active">Créer un compte</a>
</li>
```

This seems to work fine. The problem is that I get an infinite loop in the backend trying to get the user which makes the App cruches.

Here is how I wrote my method:

```
//imports here
export class AuthService {
    isLoggedIn = false;
    role: number;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .post<any>(apiUrl + 'login', data, { observe: 'response' })
            .pipe(
                tap((_) => (this.isLoggedIn = true)),
                catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
            );
    }

    //other methods here
    getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        const username = decoded.sub;
        return this.http.get<any>(apiUrl + 'users/' + username);
    }
    get isAdmin() {
        if (this.isLoggedIn) {
            this.getCurrentUser().subscribe(res => {
                this.role = res.role;
            })
                , (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        return this.role === 3;
    }
}
```

How can I stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution for my problem,
I moved this method from authService to the header component TS.
I get the role in the constructor.For the get isAdmin() I just make a return.

```
constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {
  this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(res => {
    this.role = res.role;
  })
}

ngOnInit() {}

get isAdmin() {
  return this.role === 3;
}
```